# Best practice for using Ansible from both CLI and AWX/Tower

Tags: command-line, git, automation, ansible, ansible-vault

Although the question creation form warns me that my question appears to be subjective, I still hope there are some good answers to this question that might help a lot of people.

> Are there any best practices or working examples of how to use a single directory structure for both Ansible from the CLI and from Ansible AWX/Tower?

My setup currently consists of a filesystem structure that follows [Ansible's Best Practice Directory Layout](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout) mostly. I am currently working with Git repositories in some subfolders, but I feel like it could be better.

To elaborate a little more and to zero in on my current problem I want to use ansible-vault files in my inventory, which works perfectly from the CLI but AWX cannot handle them (at time of writing). This is a specific scenario but I still think there should be an overall good practice, at one that works with as little pain as possible.

For some hands on, following is my directory structure:

```
ansible
├── ansible.cfg
├── inventory
│   ├── group_vars
│   │   └── group1
│   │       ├── vars.yml
│   │       └── vault.yml
│   ├── host_vars
│   ├── hosts.ini
│   ├── hosts.ini
├── playbooks
│   └── staging.yml
└── roles
    └── ansible-role-common
```

`inventory`, `playbooks` and `roles` are all their own git repositories. The main directory is (currently) not version controlled.

Comment: Although not directly related to your current question, the following might give you some clues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55773505/where-to-place-requirements-yml-for-ansible-and-use-it-to-resolve-dependencies/55774721#55774721 more spcifically the second part dealing with project structure.

Comment: I am terribly short on time currently but thanks a lot for bringing that to my attention! I will review your link and maybe try and built on that input.

Comment: @Zeitounator I finally found the time to review your link. Sadly I can not apply any of it to my current situation. See the updated question for more clarification.